# Interacting with Ocaml functions from F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#, ocaml

I am exploring functional programming through F# and Ocaml.
How do i call OCaml functions from a F# application and vice-versa.

Comment: It might help if you explained why you want to do this.  Normally, you would use either one or the other.

Comment: Are you aware that F# started from OCaml and in the early days you could copy OCaml code into F# and it pretty much worked. You can still copy OCaml in to F# but you have to know the differences and convert some of it by hand. [Here](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples) is a project that was originally OCaml and converted to F#.

Comment: @Foole I have  two sets of legacy projects which are created in F# and Ocaml.
I need to integrate them and call from a C# application.
The call flow would be from C# |> F# |> Ocaml

Comment: @GuyCoder Yes, I read about it. Ill check the project . Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are several different ways to do this:

- An OCaml implementation for .NET;
- An interoperability library for OCaml;
- A more generic protocol that is language-agnostic (json, protobuf).

Some useful things:

#### [OCamIL](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocamil/)

> OCamIL is an experimental OCAML compiler that targets Microsoft .NET.
>   It aims at being 100% compatible with the standard implementation developed by INRIA.

As long as you are using the standard .NET implementation of F#, you can use the
.NET implementation of OCaml and easily link things together.
However, the project last release has been in 2007, and it was never ready for
production usage.

#### [CSML](https://github.com/LexiFi/csml)

> high-levels bindings between .NET and OCaml

CSML is useful when developing OCaml under Windows. You can use .NET libraries
in your OCaml code. The project is, however, a bit old, and I'm not sure if it
is ready for production usage.

#### [JSON-RPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification)

> JSON-RPC is a stateless, light-weight remote procedure call (RPC) protocol.
>   Primarily this specification defines several data structures and the rules around
>   their processing. It is transport agnostic in that the concepts can be used within
>   the same process, over sockets, over http, or in many various message passing
>   environments. It uses JSON (RFC 4627) as data format.

This is one of the easiest ways to interface different languages without worrying
about how they were implemented, and is also the protocol used by VSCode.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try these approach.